# Authenticating mobile device

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication

I'm developing client-server application, where client applications will run on mobile devices (Android, iOS) and will communicate with the server via HTTP protocol. Mobile applications will be available for free at the market and multiple users will be using the same application instance on the same device.

I need to authenticate each request to the server and **I need to authenticate a device, not a user** and practically anybody could be in a possession of a device.

I've worked arround this solution:

**After installing the application:**

Let's presume this is done on a secure network:

1. An administrator (not a regular user) runs the application on the given device and uses app's authentication form once (filling his login and password).
2. Server authenticates the administrator and sends back a secret *device key* and a "public" *device id* specific for the device.
3. Server stores the *device key* and *device id*.
4. Device stores the *device key* in a *secure storage* and *device id* wherever.

Now the device has its own "credentials".

**With each client request:**

1. Client requests a *request key*. The request contains the *device id*.
2. Server genenerates the *request key*, stores it along with the *device id* and sends it to the client.
3. Client sends request data with *device id* and a hash of (the data + *request key* + *device key*) and thus signs the request.
4. Server checks the hash. Server also invalidates the *request key*.

**My questions:**

1. Presuming something like the *secure storage* exists: how secure would this approach be?
2. Is there anything like *secure storage* what nobody (but the only application) can read in iOS and Android? Could you provide some links to study (especially for android). Does this depend on rooting the device?

---

**Some notes:**

I believe that thanks to the *request key*, the client really needs to prove the knowledge of the secret *device key* (without the *request key* a hacker could send again intercepted data). Since the *device key* is sent over a secure network, it can not be intercepted and since it is stored in a *secure storage* it can not be stolen from the device.

However I expect there is no 100% secure storage (minimally on android) and if the device is rooted the secret *device key* can be stolen. Storing it encrypted makes it only harder for a hacker - he would need to decompile the client application and find how to decrypt it.

---

EDIT: Little change in the suggested approach (there was a security gap), added some notes and some other minor details.

Comment: Hello Lukas, I just got this problem today, do you find any solution yet on it?

Comment: Hello Chintan. Unfortunately I did not find anything better than the protocol described above. Fortunately for me, in my context that high security is not critical, I just wanted to have it as secure as possible.

In the end I basically did not write the android application, only the server. But note, there is a comment I made "data may be protected (even when a hacker has the physical accesss) using KeyChain since Android 4.3 with TPM". Maybe you want to check if it is true and has any possible use for you.

Comment: Actually, to be exact, I refined the protocol a bit: all the request keys have only time-limited duration (say 5 minutes) + some other light context-specific modifications, so nobody can mess the server by creating a lot of useless request keys, but these are details.

Comment: thanks for getting back to it Lukas, this info is much helpful

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html I think you already know about this. What about keytool and self signed certificates? I probably didn't help much.

Comment: yeah, found that too... i'm not sure now, if any other application can then get access to the saved account information... in any case, a hacker can gain access to stored information if a device is rooted... as he can if I store in any other "only for application" storage.. according to what I have found - data may be protected (even when a hacker has the physical accesss) using KeyChain since Android 4.3 with TPM (which is not very satisfying)

Comment: If it helps android is for personal devices so the system has no user accounts.however the Linux kernel upon which android was built does have users.it would be a shame to waste the functionality so what they did was repurpose it.app vendors have accounts so by default apps have access only to their own package name.you can override. This in manifest permissions and when the app is installed the user must accept the "sudo " permissions But only at install time.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is to create a web service for the login in your application on Android (of course, you need to encrypt and decrypt your login). If login succeed, save user session in sharedPreferences or other storage of your choice. After user finishs, the user can log out and user session will be destroyed.

Comment: The problem is, I really need to authenticate a device not a user (just to make sure, that the request comes from a specific device). The users won't even have any login/password, they'll have only ID.
It's no problem, however, for administrator (of the server) to login once from the device, but he can not be logging in every day and also he can not be watching the device for entire session.

Comment: Basically, I just need to make sure that a request with a given user ID comes from the right device (and administrator will manage the list of allowed devices).

Comment: to get DeviceID, you can do: Secure.getString(ContentResolver, Secure.ANDROID_ID);
However, this is kinda risky way to identify a user for your app since it is gone if user wipe device, and your user may not be able to run your app on different device.
More info on device id, check this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Thank you, I know about DeviceID, however while anybody can access a device, than anybody can also access the DeviceID and then fake the communication (act like the device).

Comment: Well, in that case, you need to come up with an algorithm to encrypt your client credential

Comment: Now the question is - will it make it secure? I've edited the original post a little - see my second note:

Storing it encrypted makes it only harder for a hacker - he would need to decompile the client application and find how to decrypt it.